# How can net profit be positive when expected payoff is negative?

Tags: investing

I was reviewing someone's trade history in [FxPrimus](http://www.fxprimus.com/) and came across this (main currency USD):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What strikes me as odd is that even though gross profit is $0, gross loss is $3649, and expected payoff is -$61, the total net profit is $3649.

How do the numbers add up to a total net profit of $3649.24?

Comment: The 'graph' didn't come through. I'm guessing, the $3649 is only for closed trades. What positions are currently open?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, no positions are opened. What may have been the cause for the discrepancy?

Comment: It's hard to read but it looks like there's a possibility that the profit came from short-selling and is being accounted for in an odd way. If you look here gross losses that lose money (odd language I know) have a negative number in them, yours is positive: http://www.mql5.com/en/signals/4789

Answer (score 2):

This is a MetaTrader4 Detailed Summary exported directly from the trading terminal.

From the looks of this statement parts of it were omitted. This could have been done directly to the statement (which is just an HTM document) to hide true P/L or this could be a limitation of their Forex broker.

Here is an example of my November summary unedited for comparison:
[image]

Comment: Hmm in my chart, if the total net profit is `-3649.24`, the numbers all fall in place right? Does MT4 usually write negative total net profit in positive (absolute-form) numbers?

Comment: Also in my chart, how could the average loss trade be greater than the *loss* loss trade?

Comment: @Pacerier completely forgot about this question, but yes numerals all numerals should be absolute. Gross Loss is inherently negative so it is a positive value. Gross Profit less Gross Loss equals Net Profit which is what the payout would be. So it is possible the Total Net Profit could be negative, indicating realized losses. As for the average being greater than the maximal, that should never be the case.